# how To search for only the latest request, while clearing previous searches from the relevant fields, one can follow this approach in laravel:

Tags: php, laravel

Imagine that I search for the name of a teacher and see the results in a list. Afterwards, I proceed to other fields and enter the search term, and then perform the search, while I do not need to search again in the first field.

```html
<form class="ml-2" id="searchForm" >
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control float-right"
                   placeholder="search" value="{{ request('search') }}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <select class="form-control" name="gender">
                <option selected disabled>gender</option>
                <option value="man" {{request('gender') == 'man' ? 'selected' : ''}}>man </option>
                <option value="woman" {{request('gender') == 'woman' ? 'selected' : ''}}> woman</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <select class="form-control" name="education">
                <option selected disabled>education</option>
                <option value="associate" {{request('education') === 'associate' ? 'selected' : '' }}>associate</option>
                <option value="post_associate" {{request('education') === 'post_associate' ? 'selected' : ''}}> post_associate</option>
                <option value="bachelor" {{request('education') === 'bachelor' ? 'selected' : ''}}>bachelor</option>
                <option value="master" {{request('education') === 'master' ? 'selected' : ''}}> master</option>
                <option value="doctoral" {{request('education') === 'doctoral' ? 'selected' : ''}}>doctoral </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100" onclick="clearFields()">search</i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $teachers = Teacher::teacherSearch($request);
    $teachers = $teachers->latest()->paginate(env('PAGINATION_SIZE'));

    return view('admin.teachers.all', compact('teachers'));
}
```

```php
public static function teacherSearch(Request $request)
{
    $query = Teacher::query();

    $search = $request->input('search');
    $gender = $request->input('gender');
    $education = $request->input('education');

    if ($search) {
        $query->where('full_name', $search)
            ->orWhere('mobile', $search)
            ->orWhere('national_code', $search);
    }

    if($gender) {
        $query->where('gender', $gender);
    }

    if($education) {
        $query->where('degree_of_education', $education);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: remove `env` from any controller, it only have to be used on the `config` file, because when you run `php artisan config:cache` or `php artisan optimize`, `env` will always return `null`...

Comment: @matiaslauriti  but my question is another thing,i want to clear pervous word of before search.it's confuse me.  for your mention about env "thank you"

Comment: For example, between two clicks on the search button, any field that was filled before the first click should be empty. @matiaslauriti